# RESTKit - postObject:path:parameters:success:failure: method always fails

Tags: ios, post, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to send a POST request to a server. I'm using RESTKit with a request descriptor:

```
RKObjectMapping *messageRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping ];
[messageRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"to", @"msg"]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:messageRequestMapping objectClass:[PostMessage class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];

[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```

and then I'm using `postObject:path:parameters:success:failure:`

```
PostMessage *postMessage = [PostMessage new];
    postMessage.to = self.pickedPerson.name;
    postMessage.msg = message.messgaeContent;
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:postMessage path:@"/post" parameters:nil
                                        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                            NSLog(@"SUCCES: message sent to server");

                                        }
                                        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            NSLog(@"WARNING");
                                              }];
```

The problem is that the failure block always gets called even though I see that the POST request got to the server successfully. When I test the same POST request with a simple REST client I get a status code of 200.

The error I get is:

`Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded." UserInfo=0x10c67adf0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=A 200 response was loaded from the URL 'http://bla.com/post', which failed to match all (0) response descriptors:, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://bla.com/post, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://bla.com/post, NSUnderlyingError=0x10c60add0 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched.", keyPath=null, NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded.}`

I'm not sure if I have to set a responseDescriptor or not.
Can't I just set the expected status code like I do when setting a responseDescriptor?

**EDIT**:
I've added a response descriptor:

```
// message response after a post
    RKObjectMapping *messageResponseForPostMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PostMessage class]];
    [messageResponseForPostMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"success"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *messageResponseForPostDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:messageResponseForPostMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                        pathPattern:@"post"
                                            keyPath:@""
                                        statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]]; 
[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[messageResponseDescriptor, personResponseDescriptor, messageResponseForPostDescriptor]];
```

as the server's response is:

```
{
  "success" : "Message sent successfully."
}
```

and it still fails with the same error.

Comment: I don't think the response structure matches the KVC pattern of the descriptor.

Comment: what do you mean? I'm new to RESTKit so I don't know it very well

Comment: The response structure should match the structure of the descriptor.

Comment: I added a response descriptor that matches the response, and it still fails with the same error (I edited the question above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't actually find what's wrong with my response descriptor.
My way of dealing with this was to change the response on the server. Instead of sending back a json file, the server now sends response code of 201, and RESTKit does not fail anymore.

Comment: If this is the case then you must have another response descriptor that is handling it, even if you didn't intend that. The correct solution is to use RestKit to create the request to send but then to use AFNetworking to send that request (because you don't care about mapping the response).

Comment: So how exactly should I send this request? Also, I tried to add a mapping, but it always kept failing. Do you what I did wrong with the responseDescriptor mapping?

Comment: `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:`. Your code looked ok, would need to see a trace log for why the response descriptor wasn't found / used.

Comment: This method you specified will work on the `[RKObjectManager sharedManager]` ? and I posted the error in the original question. Or you mean something else?

Comment: No, it's an AFNetworking method. If you always get `No response descriptors match the response loaded` then your response descriptor path is wrong or you didn't add the descriptor to the object manager.

Comment: My server needs to get some headers in the request. I though that means I have to use REST for that. Besides that, I can't figure out what is wrong with my response descriptor. I did add it to the object manager. How the `[RKObjectManager sharedManager]` knows which response descriptor to use?

Comment: It knows based on path pattern matching

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that

> "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched."

So, either you gave an incorrect response descriptor, or you did not define one.
Giving a correct response descriptor should fix the issue.

This is an example response descriptor:

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:<YOURCLASSHERE>];
...
RKResponseDescriptor * responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor
    responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
    method:RKRequestMethodPOST
    pathPattern:path keyPath:nil
    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

Comment: but I've added a response descriptor also. which match the response I get from the server which is: `{
  "success" : "Message sent successfully."
}` and it is still failing

Comment: the one you mention is a request descriptor... think of this: you send a request, that might be a post with a json payload to modify some entity; you define a request descriptor for this. The server will carry out the operation and send back its response with a json payload representing whatever makes sense for your application; you define a response descriptor for this. hope this helps.

Comment: so you mean I shouldn't have the request descriptor in the first place?

Comment: I haven't said that. You could need a request descriptor if you send out some json payload (that restkit will assemble from your objects) to your server. If you send some object, let's say so, you need a request descriptor; if you receive some object, then you also need a response descriptor. See my edit; it is not easy to do, so just try it out.

Comment: also consider that you might need to specify a `keypath` if your server wraps the object inside of a given key (e.g.: `results`).

Comment: try with `nil` for `keypath` -- `@""` will certainly not do for it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did change the response descriptor to match you answer, but it still doesn't work. I still get the same error.

Comment: yours was ok, too, with the only thing to change being the keypath... try also with `/post` for `path`, which should match the URI. if that does not work, I would debug into rest kit to understand what is happening...

Comment: thanks, I didn't figure out what was wrong with the response descriptor, but I found another way to deal with it. I posted an answer to it. Thanks anyway :)